# Blackberry jde emulator showing jvm error

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have read that by  erasing non volatile storage memory and erasing removable memory will clear this error.I did the same but after that i cannot access my sd card from simulator.Every time i have to create a new one after this error.Any other solution?

Comment: what is ur problem? please some more information

Comment: My emulator cannot retrieve data from my db in sd card after a jvm error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the clean script located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 5.0.0\5.0.0.681 (8520)\clean.bat
```

Check the version of your the emulator an the BlackBerry jdk that you are using so you can find the *clean.bat*  file